# Is there any python module to digitize the circular chart (having more than 3 line and 2 different axis)?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, data-extraction

There are multiple python based code available for digitizing the scientific line plots having 2D coordinates. I am wondering if there is any way to fetch data from circular chart with some tornado shaped axis having more than 3 lines and 2 different axis. The color of all the lines are different sample image is attached.

[image: circular chart]